# Mongoose, instant destructuring to a database document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

when fetching a document from the database, I want to destructure fields from it in one line, other ORMs such as TypeORM offer this ability out of the box, but I couldn't manage to do the same with Mongoose.

example:

```js
// working TypeORM example
const { id, name, email } = await this.userRepository.findOne({ handle: 'JohnDoe' });

// the above line is achieved with mongoose with 2 additional steps:
const doc = await this.userModel.findOne({ handle: 'JohnDoe' });
const { id } = doc;
const { name, email } = doc.toObject();
```

How to improve the mongoose example above, thanks!